# How should I handle Symfony2/Doctrine exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, exception, doctrine-orm

Maybe this is a hot topic and some others talk about this but I don't find a good solution yet to this problem. Take this error for `UNIQUE` fields as example. When I try to insert the same values to the database I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'j1234567' for key 'UNIQ_FC3A5A1592FC23A8'

Of course this happens on `app_dev.php (development)` enviroment but I don't know how to deal with this in order to show an error page to users instead of this ugly error. I test the same code at `production` then the ugly error disappear but I get this instead:

> ERROR: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Paths, I though, are more than one, for example I could check the existence of the record before I insert or before I send the request trough AJAX but I want to learn how to achieve this by using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 asserts. I have already added this code to my entities:

```
<?php

....
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * SysPerfil
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sys_perfil")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"rif"}, message="Este RIF ya existe en nuestra base de datos")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"ci"}, message="Este CI ya existe en nuestra base de datos")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nombre"}, message="Este nombre ya existe en nuestra base de datos")
 */
class SysPerfil
{
    ....
```

But it's not working since I get the error mentioned above, so what is the best way to handle this? Any ideas? Advices? Docs?

**Add form types**

Yes, I send the data trough a form type, see below:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Email',
                'trim' => true
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Contraseña',
                'always_empty' => true
            ))
            ->add('confirm', 'password', array(
                'required' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Verificar contraseña',
                'always_empty' => true
            ))
            ->add('enabled', 'checkbox', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Activo?',
                'data' => true
            ))
            ->add('perfil', new AdminPerfilType());
}
```

And `AdminPerfilType.php`:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
            ->add('persJuridica', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => RifType::getChoices(),
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'RIF',
                'trim' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'persJuridica'
                )
            ))
            ->add('roleType', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => AdminRoleType::getChoices(),
                'required' => true,
                'label' => "Tipo de Usuario",
                'trim' => true
            ))
            ->add('rif', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'trim' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => "numeric",
                    'maxlength' => 15
                )
            ))
            ->add('ci', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'CI',
                'trim' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => "numeric ci",
                    'disabled' => 'disabled'
                )
            ))
            ->add('nombre', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Nombre',
                'trim' => true
            ))
            ->add('apellido', 'text', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Apellidos',
                'trim' => true
            ));
}
```

If you're looking for validation rules inside the form then I haven't since I though that Doctrine/Symfony2 handle that part already

Comment: You can create your own [constraints validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Comment: @tttony I like that one but how I access entity manager from constraint in order to check if the value already exists on DB or not?

Comment: do u use a form to insert the entity? can you show more code ?

Comment: @ra_htial added extra information as you ask for

Comment: @ReynierPM [here](http://janosch.woschitz.org/how-to-create-a-custom-validation-constraint-in-symfony2/) a better example in how to use constraint validator, but I think it's better to use UniqueEntity()

Comment: @ReynierPM added an answer, check if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your error is because you have a Parent -> Child Entities with One-To-One mapping, your form validation is checking the parent entity validation rules without checking the child validation rules because you are not using `Assert\Valid`

Example from Symfony Documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html:

```
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Entity/Address.php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Address
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max = "5")
     */
    protected $zipCode;
}

// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Entity;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(min = "4")
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $lastName;

    //without this Symfony won't check if the inserted address is satisfying the validation rules or not 
    /**
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    protected $address;
}
```